# is it possible to forbidden inject stylesheet in google chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Now I found my google home page width changed to the min width 400(the actual screen size > 1600), when I open the google chrome console, I found it contains many inject stylesheet css. Is it possible to found where inject the stylesheet? If not, is it possible to forbidden the inject stylesheet? this is the inject stylesheet looks like:

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure those are from Boostrap, a framework meant to make it easier to develop web pages. Would need to know more about what this "google home page" you mention actually is.

Comment: is it possible to disable the bootstrap to inject css in the original page @Ouroborus

Comment: It depends on what your "google home page" is. I'm pretty sure that will screw up your page, though.